# VBA - #N/A and (Blanks) in filter-style checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to create filter style checkboxes, but do not know how to handle #N/A (which shows up as `Error 2042`) and (Blanks).

The relevant part of my code is -

```
'Read Client Type Column
ClientType = Sht.Range(StartCell, Sht.Cells(LastRow, StartCell.Column))

'Find unique client names
Set UniqueType = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = LBound(ClientType, 1) To UBound(ClientType, 1)
    UniqueType(ClientType(i, 1)) = 1
Next i  

Temp = UniqueType.Keys()

Cntr = 1

On Error Resume Next
For Each j In Temp
    Set Cbx = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
    Cbx.Caption = j
    Cbx.Left = 15
    Cbx.Top = 10 + (15 * (Cntr - 1))
    Cntr = Cntr + 1
Next j
```

I tried -

```
If UniqueType.Exists("") Then
    UniqueType.Remove ""
    UniqueType.Add "(Blanks)", 1
End If
```

which works for Blanks but not for #N/A.

When I tried -

```
ClientType = Sht.Range(StartCell, Sht.Cells(LastRow, StartCell.Column)).Text
```

I get a `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch` when I run `UniqueType(ClientType(i, 1)) = 1`.

Is there a smarter way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited after OP's clarification:

```
'Read Client Type Column
Set UniqueType = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Sht.Range(StartCell, Sht.Cells(LastRow, StartCell.Column))
    'Find unique client name
    UniqueType(cell.Text) = 1
Next

Temp = UniqueType.Keys()

'... rest of your code
```

Comment: Is there a way to include them the way it appears when we filter a column?

Comment: I don't get you, please clarify further.

Comment: Sorry. When we apply Data > Filter on a column in an Excel worksheet, if there are blanks and errors in the column, we see `(Blanks)` and `#N/A` in the options. Is there a way to achieve that?